# Including JUnit 5 dependency in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, junit5

From [jetbrains blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/08/using-junit-5-in-intellij-idea):

> IntelliJ IDEA supports the ability to actually run tests written for
>   JUnit 5 – there’s no need to use the additional libraries (like the
>   Gradle or Maven plugins for example), all you need is to include the
>   JUnit 5 dependency.

I'm new to Java and IntelliJ IDEA and it's not clear to me what are the steps that I should do for making test using Junit 5.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If your project is Maven or Gradle based, the dependency is added via `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`, otherwise you just add the `.jar` files to the [Module Dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).

IDE can help you with that, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the red code:

[image: add library]

The following dependencies will be downloaded from the Maven repository and added to the classpath:

[image: deps]

Comment: Hi and thanks for the help, I'm a completly begginer in Java so Maven and Gradle are not familiar to me. Which jar files do I need to download and from where and what should I do with them? (the IDE only letting me add JUnit 4 using alt + enter ).

Comment: Try the latest IDE version from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html.

Answer (score 7):

I made this work by adding this to my pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-M4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>       
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-M4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

Previously you need plugin to run unit test like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        // The following is only necessary if you want to use SNAPSHOT releases.
        // maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-M2'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'
```

But for JUnit5 no need of plugin just compile

```
dependencies {
     testCompile 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.0.0-M2'
}
```

Comment: Where do I write that dependencies?

Comment: write it in your build.gradle of app module

Answer (score 0):

Got the latest IntelliJ IDEA (2017.3), being able to add JUnit5 library when creating test class in IntelliJ, but still failed to find tests. Tried the suggestion by @CrazyCoder, and found out the org.junit.jupiter.api has existed in my IntelliJ and has the version 5.0.0-M6. And finally solved by downloading  *org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.0.0-M6* from Maven Repository and adding it into classpath.

For someone like me, new to the IntelliJ, the detailed steps I followed:

1. Open Project Settings -> Libraries -> + New Project Library -> from Maven...
2. Search and add *org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.0.0-M6*
3. Modules -> *module name you want to add it to* -> Dependencies -> + 2 Library ... *(should have library jar listed)*

Answer (score 0):

There is much simpler way to generate test class in IntelliJ IDEA.
*(Works on IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.3)*

1. Click on class you want to test and press alt+enter or click yellow lightbulb > pick Create Test
   [image: start test class generation]
2. Setup where and how you wish to generate test class.
   ( *Please note that IntelliJ IDEA will detect if you have appropriate JUnit and prompts you to for automatic download if you don't.* )[image: testing class generation setup]
3. Write your test class code [image]

You can find more details in [jetbrains documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-tests.html)